# Cloud Build yaml in repository and potential for bypassing permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-build

Say I have the following `cloudbuild.yaml` in my repository, and its referenced by a manual trigger during setup (ie. it looks in the repo for `cloudbuild.yaml`)

```yaml
# repo/main/cloudbuild.yaml

steps:
  - id: 'Safe step'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args: ['echo', 'hello world']
```

Assume that the intention is that users can manually run the trigger as they please. However the cloud build service account is also high-powered and has access to certain permissions that can be destructive. This is required for other manual triggers that need to be approved.

Can the user create a branch, edit the `cloudbuild.yaml` to do something destructive, push he branch up and then when they go to run the trigger they just reference their branch instead thereby bypassing the control to be able to edit a trigger?

```yaml
# repo/branch-xyz/cloudbuild.yaml

steps:
  - id: 'Safe step'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args: ['do', 'something', 'destructive']
```

Comment: I guess it depends on how the trigger is configured. From what you're describing, looks like it is matching all the branches and the Service Account being used is Cloud Build's default one. With that setup, what you're describing is correct, the trigger will execute whatever the cloudbuild.yaml has defined. You should be able to limit that behaviour by filtering the trigger by branch, limiting the service account permissions or use a custom one, or both options all together. With a combination of branch filtering and custom service accounts you have fine-grained access control.

Comment: Depends on your CI/CD configuration and permission at each stage. A new branch shouldn't be able to access to production permissions and kill all! The blast radius should be limited to the dev environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki as this is based on @bhito's comment:

It depends on how the trigger is configured.

From what you're describing, looks like it is matching all the branches and the Service Account being used is Cloud Build's default one. With that setup, what you're describing is correct, the trigger will execute whatever the cloudbuild.yaml has defined.

You should be able to limit that behaviour by filtering the trigger by branch, limiting the service account permissions or use a custom one, or both options all together. With a combination of branch filtering and custom service accounts you have fine-grained access control.